# Как получить поля вложенных элементов API через VUE JS?

Tags: json, django, vue.js, django-rest-framework, vue-router

Есть массив "Категория", в нем есть массив "Посты".

Как получить доступ к элементам поста? `{{category.posts}}` - выводится, но весь массив. `{{category.posts.title}}` -  `TypeError`:

> Cannot read property 'title' of undefined

Отмечу что для постов же выводятся вложенные поля (категория, пользователь)
`{{post.category.name}}`, `{{post.category.username}}`

А в категории не получается.

Comment: А в чем собственно проблема? `<div v-for="post in category.posts">{{ post.title }}</div>`, это во-первых, во-вторых у Вас `posts => undefined`, а точнее такого свойства вообще нету в `category`

Comment: Posts массив у вас.

Comment: @overthesanity благодарю, что-то я совсем ступил с неопытности)